# Biholomorphic $f:\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|<1,~Im(z)>0\}\rightarrow\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|<1\}$

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

Is there a bijective holomorphic function $$f:\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|<1,~Im(z)>0\}\rightarrow\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|<1\}$$ such that $f^{-1}$ is holomorphic?

You can give me a composition of functions. For example: If you know a biholomorphic function $$f_0:\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|<1,~Im(z)>0\}\rightarrow\{z\in\mathbb{C}:Im(z)>0\}=:H$$ that's enough as the function $$f_1:H\rightarrow\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|<1\}$$ is biholomorphic.

Comment: If a holomorphic function is a bijection, its inverse is automatically holomorphic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The map $z \to \frac{1+z}{1-z}$ takes the upper-half disk to the first quadrant. Now use the squaring map $z \to z^2$ to complete the answer.

Comment: Why does your function maps the upper-half disk to the first quadrant? And why bijective? :)

Comment: @N.Sch You can figure that out using the basic facts about linear-fractional transformations: They take (lines and circles) to (lines and circles) and they preserve angles.

Comment: Are you *sure* your composition is onto?

Comment: @EricTowers As long as nobody else is saying: Of course SS said that one can now do whatever to complete the answer, without saying exactly what the answer was. I'm not sure what part you're skeptical about. The map from the upper half-disk to the first quadrant does in fact map the upper half-disk onto the first quadrant. Now squaring maps the first quadrant onto the upper half-plane, and we all know how to map the upper half-plane onto the disk. (So in your answer and this one we see two different ways to map "half" of $H$ onto $H$. This one seems more straighforward;[...]

Comment: @EricTowers [...] Otoh I learned something from all this: Given that both solutions are correct, the two different maps from half of $H$ onto $H$ must be equivalent, modulo $Aut(H)$. This makes the $z+1/z$ thing much less mysterious to me...)

Answer (score 0):

What a familiar looking question.  Saw this with a one unit pre-translation on a qualifying exam today.

We write a sequence of transformations, each of which is a conformal equivalence (a biholomorphism):

- $\mu_1$: from the open upper half disk to $\Pi^+ \setminus \overline{\Bbb{D}}$, the upper half plane without the closed unit disk: $z \mapsto-1/z$.
- $\mu_2$: from $\Pi^+ \setminus \overline{\Bbb{D}}$ to $\Pi^+$: $z \mapsto \frac{1}{2}\left(z+\dfrac{1}{z}\right)$.  One should probably show that this map holds $\Bbb{R} \setminus (-1,1)$ fixed and takes the upper unit semicircle $\{\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}t} : 0<t<\pi\}$ to $(-1,1)$ via the cosine.
- $\mu_1^{-1}$: from $\Pi^+$ to $\Bbb{D}$.

Then $\mu_1^{-1} \circ \mu_2 \circ \mu_1$ maps your set biholomorphically to the open unit disk.

Edit:  Fixed the missing $\frac{1}{2}$ in $\mu_2$ and stopped claiming $\mu_2(z) = \frac{1+z^2}{2z}$ was a Möbius transform.

Comment: Clearly can't be done with  Möbius transformations, since the image of a circle under a  Möbius transformation is a (line or a) circle. Curiously, the answer is nonetheless very easily fixed...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich : Fixed, I think.

Comment: Heh. I believe so as well.